# MySQL - Stored Procedure - Only getting last record with while loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to keep adding all the values of price from a table. I have tried
n_total_price = n_total_price + d_price;

It's a assignment, I have to use a stored procedure

It just gives me the last record

```
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE P_TOTAL_PRICES(OUT N_TOTAL_PRICE DECIMAL(30,2))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE D_PRICE DECIMAL(30,2);
        DECLARE ABC DECIMAL(30,2);
        DECLARE FOUND BOOLEAN;
        DECLARE CURSOR_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCT;
        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FOUND = FALSE;
        SET FOUND = TRUE;
        OPEN CURSOR_1;
        FETCH CURSOR_1 INTO ABC;
        WHILE FOUND DO 
            SET N_TOTAL_PRICE = N_TOTAL_PRICE + D_PRICE;
            FETCH CURSOR_1 INTO ABC;
        END WHILE;
        CLOSE CURSOR_1;
    END; $$
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM PRODUCT`?

Comment: Maybe you need to declare `N_TOTAL_PRICE` and set it to `0` before the loop. Then `SET N_TOTAL_PRICE = N_TOTAL_PRICE + D_PRICE` should work.

Comment: as @Barmar you've written about 20 lines for what can be done in one line.

Comment: It's a assignment, I have to use a stored procedure

Comment: n_total_price set to 0 before the loop worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE P_TOTAL_PRICES(OUT N_TOTAL_PRICE DECIMAL(30,2))
BEGIN
DECLARE D_PRICE DECIMAL(30,2);
DECLARE ABC DECIMAL(30,2);
DECLARE FOUND BOOLEAN;
DECLARE CURSOR_1 CURSOR FOR SELECT PRICE FROM PRODUCT;
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET FOUND = FALSE;
SET FOUND = TRUE;
OPEN CURSOR_1;
FETCH CURSOR_1 INTO ABC;
**SET N_TOTAL_PRICE = 0;**
WHILE FOUND DO SET N_TOTAL_PRICE = N_TOTAL_PRICE +D_PRICE;
FETCH CURSOR_1 INTO ABC;
END WHILE;
CLOSE CURSOR_1;
END; $$
```